# How to consolidate multiple non-continuous ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to consolidate values in multuple non-continuous range, but I fail to do this. Like my example below

```
  Set myRange = Range("E6:F8,E12:F14")

  [J10].Consolidate Sources:=myRange,  _
    Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

I know I can copy all ranges in one place and then consolidate in a continuous range, like

```
  [J10].Consolidate Sources:=TempSheet.Range(A1:B10).Address,  _
    Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

Answer (score 2):

[Consolidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839594(v=office.15).aspx) requires full path of Sheets and Sources in R1C1 style

```
Sub MyConsolidate()
 [J10].Consolidate _
 Sources:=Array("Sheet1!R6C5:R8C6", "Sheet1!R12C5:R14C6"), _
 Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
End Sub
```

[image]

Also to convert A1 Notation to R1C1 use

```
Sub RangeToR1c1()
MsgBox Range("E6").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I can't just add `Source:=myRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`